# How to implement click listeners for an item of a RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have implemented `recyclerview` in a fragment. Now I want to click an item of `recyclerview` and then go to the next `Activity`. I have called `OnclickListener` inside `OnBindViewHolder` of the `adapter` class but it's not working. Please help me out to solve this issue.

I am going to post all codes below.

> Fragment Home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".view.ui.HomeFragment">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
        layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svSearchCountry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_rectangle_edittext"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbarHome"
        app:queryBackground="@null"
        app:queryHint="Search Country" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCountries"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/svSearchCountry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> layout_country_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCountry"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:src="@drawable/kenya"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCountryName"
        style="@style/CustomTextViewMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kenya"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ivCountry" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> CountriesAdapter.kt

```
package com.logicielhouse.tripo.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.R
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.model.CountriesModel
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.view.ui.HomeActivity
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

/**
 * Created by Abdullah on 9/10/2020.
 */
class CountriesAdapter(
    val context: Context, var countriesList: ArrayList<CountriesModel>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesAdapter.CountriesViewHolder>(), Filterable {

    var countryFilterList = ArrayList<CountriesModel>()

    init {
        countryFilterList = countriesList
    }

    inner class CountriesViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val ivCountryImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCountry)
        val tvCountryTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCountryName)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountriesViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_country_item, parent, false)
        return CountriesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val countryItem = countryFilterList[position]
        Glide.with(holder.ivCountryImage.context).load(countryItem.imageURI)
            .into(holder.ivCountryImage)
        holder.tvCountryTitle.text = countryItem.title
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            context.startActivity(Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countryFilterList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val charSearch = constraint.toString()
                countryFilterList = if (charSearch.isEmpty()) {
                    countriesList
                } else {
                    val resultList = ArrayList<CountriesModel>()
                    for (row in countriesList) {
                        if (row.title.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                                .contains(charSearch.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))
                        ) {
                            resultList.add(row)
                        }
                    }
                    resultList
                }
                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = countryFilterList
                return filterResults
            }

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                countryFilterList = results?.values as ArrayList<CountriesModel>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

> HomeFragment.kt

```
package com.logicielhouse.tripo.view.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.R
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.adapter.CountriesAdapter
import com.logicielhouse.tripo.model.CountriesModel
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var countriesAdapter: CountriesAdapter
    lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setupUI()
        setupRecyclerView()
        setupListeners()
    }

    private fun setupListeners() {
        svSearchCountry.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                countriesAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }
        })
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        countriesAdapter =
            CountriesAdapter(
                requireContext(),
                CountriesModel.countriesList as ArrayList<CountriesModel>
            )

        rvCountries.apply {
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            adapter = countriesAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun setupUI() {
        toolbar.title = "Home"

        val searchIcon = svSearchCountry.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_mag_icon)
        searchIcon.setColorFilter(R.color.colorPrimary)
        val cancelIcon = svSearchCountry.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.search_close_btn)
        cancelIcon.setColorFilter(R.color.colorText)
        val textView = svSearchCountry.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.search_src_text)
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity as MainActivity, R.color.colorText))
    }
}
```

Comment: In your click listener change your code like this and try `holder.itemView.context.startActivity(Intent(holder.itemView.context, HomeActivity::class.java))` I am not sure but you can try this.

Comment: No it is not working. It is freezing my app at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, the only problem is that you're trying to set the OnClickListener to the `itemView` itself and not one of its children, this means that when you click on an item, you don't want that item's children to gain focus.

So now what you need to do is to give your `itemView` the ability to be clicked and focused, and remove these features from its children, do this by adding to your `itemView` (which is the parent `ConstraintLayout` in the `layout_country_item.xml`):

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

And the same for the children but with a `false` value.

Comment: Added these properties with true values to Constraint parent and with false to all child but still it not working

Comment: @AbdullahJaved Have you tried debugging your code? is the `onClick()` ever called?

Comment: I tried debugger, but it is not calling. Also I have shift my click listener code from onBindViewHolder to onCreateViewHolder but still its not calling.

Comment: Since you tried `holder.itemView.context.startActivity(Intent(holder.itemView.context, HomeActivity::class.java))` as @NayanSarder suggested and it freezes your app when you click on the item, this actually means the onClick is being called, and your problem is somewhere else

Comment: Try printing log messages from within your `onClick` method. I believe they should work

Comment: When i use glide then clicklistener is not working but for setImageResource it's working perfectly xd

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should not set the context object to the adapter. if you do not pay attention, the issue may occur memory leak.

You can create an interface named CountriesAdapterListener like this:

```
public interface CountriesAdapterListener {
    fun onClickedItem()
}
```

later, you set the interface object instead of the context object at the constructor.

then you can replace code like below:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val countryItem = countryFilterList[position]
    Glide.with(holder.ivCountryImage.context).load(countryItem.imageURI)
        .into(holder.ivCountryImage)
    holder.tvCountryTitle.text = countryItem.title
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.onClickedItem()
    }
}
```

Lastly, You implementation CountriesAdapterListener inside HomeFragment.kt like this:

```
val listener = object: CountriesAdapterListener {
    override fun onClickedItem() {
        startActivity(Intent(requireActivity(), HomeActivity::class.java))
    }
}
...
...
...
private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    countriesAdapter =
        CountriesAdapter(
            listener,
            CountriesModel.countriesList as ArrayList<CountriesModel>
        )
        ...
}
```

Comment: Updated code with your help. but still I am unable to click item